# Website color looking strange in laptop when compared to other devices

Tags: colors, responsive-design, device

I have designed a responsive website with the body background color:#692775.But My website color looking darker in laptop when compared to other devices.How to fix this color variation issue for different devices?

Comment: you're never going to get two different screens to display the same color the same way, unless you're willing to spend bucks on calibration.

Comment: Screen brightness and contrast will vary. It's ultimately outwith your control.

Comment: To add, I actually once had different tabs on a Mac with the same site design with different blue colors.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty much impossible since devices display colours differently.
If you have for example 2 different brand monitors you will notice that the color will differ from eachother.

You really can't help this unless you can convince every visitor of your site to use the same device.

If you want to know the proper colour you also need to buy an rather expensive monitor which actually should match the printed result.

I would suggest making a print and decide if the colour you want looks good on paper aswell.